# X++ assign Enum Value to a table column

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am trying to pull the `Enum` chosen from a `dialog` and assign the `label` to a table's column.

For example: `Dialog` opens and allows you to choose from:

> Surface
>
> OutOfSpec
>
> Other

These are 0,1,2 respectively.

The user chooses `OutOfSpec` (the label for this is *Out Of Spec*), I want to put this enum's Name, or the label, into a table. The column I'm inserting into is set to be a `str`.

Here's the code I've tried, without success:

```
    SysDictEnum dictEnum = new SysDictEnum(enumNum(SDILF_ScrapReasons));

    reason = dialog.addField(enumStr(SDILF_ScrapReasons),"Scrap Reason");
    dialog.run();
    if (!dialog.closedOk())
    {
        info(reason.value());
        return;
    }

    ttsBegin;
    // For now, this will strip off the order ID from the summary fields.
    // No longer removing the Order ID
    batchAttr = PdsBatchAttributes::find(itemId, invDim.inventBatchId, "OrderId");
    orders = SDILF_BreakdownOrders::find(batchAttr.PdsBatchAttribValue, true);
    if (orders)
    {
        orders.BoxProduced -= 1;
        orders.update();
    }
    // Adding a batch attribute that will include the reason for scrapping
    select forUpdate batchAttr;    
    batchAttr.PdsBatchAttribId = "ScrapReason";
    //batchAttr.PdsBatchAttribValue = any2str(dictEnum.index2Value(reason.value()));
    batchAttr.PdsBatchAttribValue = enum2str(reason.value());
    batchAttr.InventBatchId = invDim.inventBatchId;
    batchAttr.ItemId = itemId;
    batchAttr.insert();
```

Obviously this is not the whole code, but it should be enough to give the issue that I'm trying to solve.

I'm sure there is a way to get the `int` value and use that to assign the label, I've just not been able to figure it out yet.

***EDIT***

To add some more information about what I am trying to accomplish. We make our finished goods, sometimes they are out of spec or damaged when this happens we then have to scrap that finished good. When we do this we want to keep track of why it is being scrapped, but we don't want just a bunch of random reasons. I used an `enum` to limit the reasons. When the operator clicks the button to scrap something they will get a dialog screen pop-up that allows them to select a reason for scrapping. The code will then, eventually, put that assigned reason on that finished items batch attributes so that we can track it later in a report and have a list of all the finished goods that were scrapped and why they were scrapped.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://rahulmsdax.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-get-label-from-enum-value-in-ax-x.html ?

Comment: I don't understand why you would store the label in the DB. This is one of the problems that is solved by enums. Why are you trying to use them in a way they are not designed? I don't know your exact requirement, but I imagine using a table with master data+lookup instead of an enum is probably the correct tool for the job.

Comment: @rjv my guess is some 3rd party integration is looking at AX SQL directly and they need to present the labels/values.

Comment: @rjv I am putting the label into the batch attributes of a finished good that has been scrapped.

Comment: @FH-Inway, I've tried something kind of like that, but how do I tell that which `enum` to use? The end-user picks one from a dialog, then whatever they pick is what I want to get the label from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your question, but I think you're just missing one of the `index2[...]` calls or you're not getting the return value from your dialog correctly. Just create the below as a new job, run it, make a selection of `Open Order` and click ok.

I don't know the difference between `index2Label` and `index2Name`.

```cs
static void Job67(Args _args)
{
    Dialog          dialog      = new dialog();
    SysDictEnum     dictEnum    = new SysDictEnum(enumNum(SalesStatus));
    DialogField     reason;
    SalesStatus     salesStatusUserSelection;
    str             label, name, symbol;
    int             value;

    reason = dialog.addField(enumStr(SalesStatus), "SalesStatus");
    dialog.run();

    if (dialog.closedOk())
    {
        salesStatusUserSelection = reason.value();

        // Label
        label = dictEnum.index2Label(salesStatusUserSelection);

        // Name
        name = dictEnum.index2Name(salesStatusUserSelection);

        // Symbol
        symbol = dictEnum.index2Symbol(salesStatusUserSelection);

        // Value
        value = dictEnum.index2Value(salesStatusUserSelection);

        info(strFmt("Label: %1; Name: %2; Symbol: %3; Value: %4", label, name, symbol, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been making this way too hard! The `index2Label` is exactly what I needed. for some reason I was thinking that then would still need to be translated into a string